# Rails When submitting a form ,always show me the error: Routing Error No route matches "blablabla"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes

My app is simple :

A controller :"main"
      with 3 actions : "welcome","form_receiver" and "result"

and 2 views : "result.html.erb" and "welcome.html.erb"

All I want to do is posting the form in "welcome.html.erb" to the action "form_receiver" and show some result in the "result" action.

But after post the form, I get the error :Routing Error No route matches "/main/form_receiver"
,through I am quite sure that I have include the path in routes.

BELOW ARE MY CODE

**controllers/main_controller.rb :**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def welcome
    #Nothing
  end

  def form_receiver
    @p = params[:customer]
    redirect_to :controller => "main",:action=>"result"
  end

  def result

  end
end
```

**views/main/welcome.html.erb :**

```
<h1>Main#welcome</h1>
<%= form_tag :controller => 'main',
             :action     => 'form_receiver'  do%>
<p>name : <%= text_field "customer","nick" %> </p>
<p>pwd : <%= password_field "customer","password" %></p>
<p><input type="Submit" value="sign up"/> </p>
<% end %>
```

**views/main/result.html.erb :**

```
<%=@p['cick']%>
<%=@p['password'] %>
```

**config/routes.rb :**

```
TestForm::Application.routes.draw do
  get "main/welcome"

  get "main/result"

  get "main/form_receiver"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you are **posting** to `form_receiver`. But you wrote `get` in the routes.rb.

So you should:

```
post "main/form_receiver"
```

Comment: thanks,i just begin learning rails and i know little about what 'get' really means here when i wrote it,thanks so much.